# Where is the Android StrictMode implemented?

Tags: android, android-strictmode

I'm looking to extend the [StrictMode API](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/StrictMode.html), similar to what is suggested [in this StackOverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4433629/detecting-forgotten-sqlite-transaction-on-android-using-strictmode).  I saw that the API was extended in Honeycomb to include a detectCustomSlowMethod() API, which sounds like it could handle some extension cases (although I'm not sure what it does because the documentation is copy-pasted from the disk methods).

However, I want to extend the API to include additional hardware access detection, which isn't possible with the API.  Therefore, my question is where can I find the code that implements the StrictMode API?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> where can I find the code that implements the StrictMode API?

In [the Android source code](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/master/core/java/android/os/StrictMode.java).

Answer (score 1):

Here's the main Java interface:

https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/master/core/java/android/os/StrictMode.java

The implementations is all over the Android guts, though.